# Firebase push get key with sdk 9 modular approach

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the question asks I'm attempting to get the key after I push to a firebase db.

```
 push(dbRef, formState)
 .then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp);
 })
 .catch(error => {
   Alert.alert(error)
 })
```

The above console.log gives me the full url of the data pushed.  In example:

```
"https://example.firebaseio.com/organization/asdfasdfasdf/members/-N08ScImBoOckVIRu-AU". I need the key only: `-N08ScImBoOckVIRu-AU`
```

I incorrectly attempted:

```
 push(dbRef, formState)
 .getKey()
 .then((resp) => {
 })
 .catch(error => {
   Alert.alert(error)
 })
```

This gives an error.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you split the `push()` call from the actual writing of the data, you can get the key like this:

```
const newRef = push(dbRef);
console.log(newRef.key);
set(newRef, formState);
```